# Drive Dropdown option from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I drive the value of the dropdown option from the servlet?..strong text 
First time user access configuration
User Selects option from drop down window, Option forwarded to servlet, Option Stored in DB. -> Option reloaded in webpage user sees option selected not first option

JSP code snippet:

```
<form class="center-container" method="post" action="ReloadFormPageServlet">
    <tr>
        <td><%String formLogoLocation=(String)request.getAttribute("formLogoLocation"); %>
            <class="ui-field-contain"><label for="formlogoLocation">Form Logo Location:</label></td><td>
            <select name = "formLogoLocation" id = "formLogoLocation">
                <option value = "1">Upper Left</option>
                <option value = "2">Upper Center</option>
                <option value = "3">Upper Right</option>
            </select>                   
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Servlet code snippet:

```
request.setAttribute("formLogoLocation", formLogoLocation);
RequestDispatcher formreload = request.getRequestDispatcher("formmanagement.jsp");
formreload.forward(request, response)
```

Comment: <%String formLogoLocation=(String)request.getAttribute("formLogoLocation"); %>
     <class="ui-field-contain"><label for="formlogoLocation">Form Logo Location:</label></td><td>
     <select name = "formLogoLocation" id = "formLogoLocation">
      <option value = "1">Upper Left</option>
      <option value = "2">Upper Center</option>
      <option value = "3">Upper Right</option>
      <option value = "4">Lower Left</option>
      <option value = "5">Lower Center</option>
      <option value = "6">Lower Right</option>
      <option value = "7">No logo</option>
     </select>

Comment: I reviewed the link and it worked like a charm for me..thanks a lot!!!!